# Keyup event fires automatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

In my winforms application for visual studio 2010,

I have a button, and two combobox(`combobox1`,`combobox2`).

I have added code in button to clear the previously entered data in first combobox(combobox1) and set focus to it.

In keyup event of first combobox(`combobox1`), I have checked for enter key, if pressed, focus will move to next combobox(`combobox2`).

But my problem is, when i press button(by pressing enter while focus is on button), focus is directly moved to last(second) combobox(`combobox2`).

Keyup event of combobox1 is automatically fired though i have entered on button only

How can i solve this?

My code is give below

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'code to perform database action
    Me.ComboBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If Me.ComboBox1.SelectedText = String.Empty Then
            ComboBox2.Focus()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update**

When i click on button, problem do not appear
But when i press enter while focus is on button, to fire the button click event, problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to change ComboBox1 to be a KeyDown handler not key up.

The reason it happens is the sequence of events:

- Key Down on Button (Enter key)
- Code runs (`Button2_Click`), focus moves to ComboBox1
- Key Up on ComboBox1 fires
- Code runs (`ComboFox1_KeyUp`), focus moves to ComboBox2

**Edit:**
A more wordy explanation: You press the enter key down on `button1`, which causes it's OnKeyDown handler to run.  By the time you have released the enter key, focus is on `Combobox1`, and so it's OnKeyUp handler runs.

Comment: thanks, it worked. but can you explain in details why the problem was occuring?

Comment: @HemalRathod: I thought I had, but I have added a more wordy explanation for you.